# Mapping buttons to controllers in Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I have these buttons:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="Test 1" value="Test 1">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="Test 2" value="Test 2">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="Test 3" value="Test 3">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="Test 4" value="Test 4">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="Test 5" value="Test 5">
</form>
```

I want each button to map to a separate controller like so:

```
@GetMapping("/panels")
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("TEST 1!");
}

@GetMapping("/panels")
public void test2() {
    System.out.println("TEST 2!");
}

@GetMapping("/panels")
public void test3() {
    System.out.println("TEST 3!");
}

@GetMapping("/panels")
public void test4() {
    System.out.println("TEST 4!");
}

@GetMapping("/panels")
public void test5() {
    System.out.println("TEST 5!");
}
```

How do I do that? I haven't found an explanation that works and/or that I understand. (I'm very new to Spring Boot.)

EDIT:

I ended up using a variation of the code I accepted as the answer. I just changed it a little so that it would still display my panels page after each button was pressed. Here's what it looks like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("all-panels")
public class PanelsController {
    @GetMapping()
    public String allPanels() {
        System.out.println("BASE PANELS PAGE!");
        return "panels";
    }

    @GetMapping("/panel1")
    public String test1() {
        System.out.println("TEST 1!");
        return "panels";
    }

    @GetMapping("/panel2")
    public String test2() {
        System.out.println("TEST 2!");
        return "panels";
    }

    @GetMapping("/panel3")
    public String test3() {
        System.out.println("TEST 3!");
        return "panels";
    }

    @GetMapping("/panel4")
    public String test4() {
        System.out.println("TEST 4!");
        return "panels";
    }

    @GetMapping("/panel5")
    public String test5() {
        System.out.println("TEST 5!");
        return "panels";
    }
}
```

```
<form>
    <button class="button" type="submit" formaction="/all-panels/panel1">Test1</button>
    <button class="button" type="submit" formaction="/all-panels/panel2">Test2</button>
    <button class="button" type="submit" formaction="/all-panels/panel3">Test3</button>
    <button class="button" type="submit" formaction="/all-panels/panel4">Test4</button>
    <button class="button" type="submit" formaction="/all-panels/panel5">Test5</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The way you do this is by sending a request to your server for every button click so you will need some scripting as well on your html. One thing that you need to be aware is that an HTML form will submit the whole content of the form to the end point specified on the `form` tag, you can change it dynamically but it would send all content to that particular endpoint. So for this particular use case you could ditch the form and use just the buttons and javascript calls. You can have a single function to send the request and on the button onclick you pass in the endpoint you want to reach.

Comment: By the way this has nothing to do with SpringBoot per se. It is just how to send a request to a server.

Comment: Here is a link of a plain javascript function to send the request to a specific URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4033310/460557

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that you will need to differentiate your endpoints. They are currently all using the `GET` method at `/panels` and the application won’t know which one to send requests to. You could make it `/panels/test1`, `/panels/test2` and so on.

Comment: @CalvinP. I was solely focused on the form part of it that I didn't even looked at the endpoints on the java code! Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the following

```
  <form>
     <button type="submit" formaction="http://localhost:8080/all-panels/panel1">Test1</button>
     <button type="submit" formaction="http://localhost:8080/all-panels/panel2">Test2</button>
     <button type="submit" formaction="http://localhost:8080/all-panels/panel3">Test3</button>
     <button type="submit" formaction="http://localhost:8080/all-panels/panel4">Test4</button>
     <button type="submit" formaction="http://localhost:8080/all-panels/panel5">Test5</button>
  </form>
```

And then use a  controller like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("all-panels")
public class PanelsController {

   @GetMapping("/panel1")
   public void test1() {
      System.out.println("TEST 1!");
   }

   @GetMapping("/panel2")
   public void test2() {
      System.out.println("TEST 2!");
   }

   @GetMapping("/panel3")
   public void test3() {
      System.out.println("TEST 3!");
   }

   @GetMapping("/panel4")
   public void test4() {
      System.out.println("TEST 4!");
   }

   @GetMapping("/panel5")
   public void test5() {
      System.out.println("TEST 5!");
   }

}
```

Keep in mind that while you develop your application you normally have both backend and frontend in your machine so the following will work `formaction="http://localhost:8080/all-panels/panel1"`

When however deployed for production the frontend will normally be the client sitting in his own computer. So then for this to work you will have to do

`formaction="{backend-url}:{backend-port}/all-panels/panel1"`

where {backend-url} is the domain where this is deployed and {backend-port} the port that your backend is listening to.

Comment: Adding onto this, I can shorting formaction down to formaction="/all-panels/panel1" instead of needing the whole url.